# Sorting and grouping points

Tags: c#, sorting, computational-geometry

I have a fairly simple object with shape defined by 12 vertices. When doing hidden lines calculation on this object(I am using Cad Control to do this) it returns collection of lines making up the shape which is usually much more than minimum count of lines to draw such a shape, please see attached picture:
[image]

Each segment between points is a line. I would like to remove points that are marked in red color leaving only minimum count (yellow cross) necessary to draw shape.

One approach would be to sort them clockwise and then loop through them checking if a cross product of three adjacent points in the list is zero and then deleting the middle one. Unfortunately, it is impossible to predict, how points will be sorted, therefore this is not an option.

Second approach would be to loop through the collection of lines offered by cad control and to find all points that are on the same line, sort them (pointsLineA, pointsLineB, pointsLineC, etc) From there it would be much easier.

So far I have accomplished that I loop through line collection (get each lines points) and in nested loop I loop through the same collection(copy of it) to check if the points of any random line in the collection lie on the same line as points from line from first loop. This involves two loops and modifying collections on the run. To make it short, it is a MESS. If you would like to see code sample, please let me know.
To make sure everything is clear - my first objective is to group points so that in each group would appear points only belonging to one line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the data from Cad you have to work with? (for the above shape)

Comment: Finding aligned points won't work. In your example, the four leftmost yellow crosses are aligned but don't belong to a single line.

Comment: On the picture, we can see the extraneous vertices, but we can't see what are the line segments. They could be overlapping.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, of course, I didn't realize that those points are also aligned! And yes, I found out that line segments sometime are also overlapping. I guess that introduces new problem. Now I am completely lost.

Comment: @erotavlas The only available data is collection of segment2D which contains startPoint, endPoint, midPoint, length and normal for each segment2D. That is what I have.

Answer (score 0):

With 12 vertices (or hundreds of vertices) I wouldn't do space partitioning (I'm thinking about adaptive quadtree, 2D-tree (kd-tree with k=2)).
I'd store for each vertex which lines it belongs to (it's easier to assign an ID to each vertex and line instead of comparing each time the coordinates of vertices).

```
vertex(1)=(2.5,3.97)  <- vertex coordinates
vertex(2)=( 13.453 , 24.687 ) 

lines_for_Vertex(1)= {1,5} if vertex 1 is member of lines 1 and 5
lines_for_Vertex(3)={2,5,7} if vertex 3 is member of lines 2,5 and 7
lines_for_vertex(9)={4} if vertex 9 is member of line 4 (edge or segment not connected)
lines_for_vertex(3)={} if vertex 3 is not connected (not member of any segment)
(maybe some cases are impossible for you)
```

You can assign ID to lines with position inside your collection of lines.

In any case, if you do this changes or keep your collections of lines, inside the nested loops you have to collect information of point to be deleted without changing anything.
So instead of doing:

```
if vertices are aligned then remove the vertex in the middle
```

you fill a list 'to_remove' with this information:

```
to_remove.add(vertex in the middle)         <- with the ID is easier
```

Then when the two loops end, you can remove all the vertices collected in the list. If you have the array 'lines_for_vertex' it's easy to find the two segments to be collapsed into one (eg. if vertex to remove is 1, the collapsing lines are 1 and 5).

If you build a structure even for lines, referring to ID of its vertices

```
e.g. line(5)={1,3} if line with ID=5 connects vertices 1 and 3
```

(compare with lines_for_vertex above), it's easier to know how to collapse lines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the topology of the polygon. The means to rearrange the vertices in a closed loop. By comparing the endpoint coordinates, you can find those that match and obtain a graph with edges between endpoints, and endpoints merged.

From this representation you can easily detect and remove the alignments.